# how to get formatted testcase Id in Rally using the rest Api

Tags: java, rest, rally

I have the testcase object ID value retrieved from Rally URL. I need its formatted ID value from that value. Can this be achieved using the rally's rest api(java)? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have ObjectID, and include FormattedID in your fetch, you may get it as in this example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
        String apiKey = "_abc123"; 
        String applicationName = "Find TestCase by ObjectID"; 
        String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12345"; 

        RallyRestApi restApi = null;
        try {
            restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);

            QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            request.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
            restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);
            request.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID"));

            request.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("ObjectID", "=", "14226025324")); 

            QueryResponse response = restApi.query(request);
            if(response.wasSuccessful()){
                System.out.println("Number of results: " + response.getResults().size());
                for (int i=0; i<response.getTotalResultCount();i++){
                    JsonObject jsonObject = response.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    System.out.println("FormattedID: " + jsonObject.get("FormattedID"));
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("false? " + response.wasSuccessful());
            }
        } finally {
            if (restApi != null) {
                restApi.close();
            }
        }
    }
```